# Optimizing a neural network with a multi-task objective in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

In deep learning, you typically have an objective (say, image recognition), that you wish to optimize. In my field (natural language processing), though, we've seen a rise of multitask training. For instance, in next sentence prediction and sentence classification in a single system.

I understand how to build the forward pass, e.g. for a classification task (obj1) and a regression task (obj2)

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = Linear(300, 200)
        self.obj1 = Linear(200, 5)
        self.obj2 = Linear(200, 1)

    def forward(inputs):
        out = self.linear(inputs)
        out_obj1 = self.obj1(out)
        out_obj2 = self.obj2(out)
        return out_obj1, out_obj2
```

But the question then becomes, **how does one optimize this**. Do you call a backward pass over both losses separately? Or do you reduce them to a single loss (e.g. sum, average)? Is there an approach that is typically used for multi-task learning?

And to follow up on that, perhaps one could even argue that the parameters of the separate layers need different optimizers. In such case, the losses must be dealt with separately, I presume.

Comment: What is the effect of not cloning the object "out" for obj1. ie out_obj1 = self.obj1(out.clone())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is much simpler, you can optimize all variables at the same time without a problem. Just compute both losses with their respective criterions, add those in a single variable:

```py
total_loss = loss_1 + loss_2
```

and calling `.backward()` on this total loss (still a Tensor), works perfectly fine for both. You could also weight the losses to give more importance to one rather than the other.

Check the [PyTorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-combine-multiple-criterions-to-a-loss-function/348) for more information.

Comment: But by doing so it might very well be the case that you are optimizing for one problem, right? It might be that the loss of loss_2 decreases a lot, but that the loss of loss_1 increases (but a bit less), and then your system is not equally optimizing them.

Comment: It could be the case, that's why I suggest a weighted sum. However, if both tasks are correlated and can be improved by being trained together, both will probably decrease their loss. Also, be sure that both loses are in the same magnitude, or it could happen what you are asking, that the greater is "nullifying" any possible change on the smaller.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy keep in mind that backward once on the sum of losses is mathematically equivalent to backward twice, once for each loss.

Comment: @jodag Could you elaborate on that? The math of the backward pass is not very clear to me.

Comment: @JosepJoestar Makes sense. I imagine when could do something like average each loss by a tasks average value and then sum, or something similar. Thanks!

Comment: @Bram Vanroy For sum case say you have loss L = L1 + L2. Consider the gradient of weights W. By linearity of differentiation you clearly have gradW = dL/dW = dL1/dW + dL2/dW. Instead if you first compute gradients for L1, then you have gradW = dL1/dW, then an additional backward pass on L2 which accumulates the gradients w.r.t L2 on top of the existing gradients which gives you gradW = gradW + dL2/dW = dL1/dW + dL2/dW = dL/dW. This is the same as the sum case, but at the cost of an additional backward pass.

Comment: @jodag That seems to make sense. I take your word for it. Thanks!

Comment: Shameless plug: I wrote a little helper library that makes it easier to compose multi task layers and losses and combine them. Feel free to check it out: [torchMTL](https://github.com/chrisby/torchMTL).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the question was answered, but here I'm trying to give some sort of further hints.

In multi-task learning, the goal is to train a single model on multiple tasks simultaneously. This can lead to improved generalization and efficiency, especially when the tasks are related inherently. Your question pertains to how to optimize such a model, particularly with regard to handling the loss functions for different tasks.

Here's a breakdown of the typical approaches:

**Combining Losses:**

- **Summing Losses:** The simplest way to combine multiple losses is to sum them up. This approach assumes that all tasks are equally important. The combined loss is then used for backpropagation.
- **Weighted Sum:** If the tasks are not equally important or if you want the network learns one of the task (over the others) faster for any reason, a weighted sum of the losses can be used. This involves multiplying each task's loss by a weight before summing them up. The weights are generally hyperparameters that you can tune based on the relative importance of each task, though you can also make them a learnable parameter, which is not a common approach as far as I know.
- **Dynamic Weighting:** More advanced techniques involve dynamically adjusting the weights during training, based on the model’s performance on each task. To this end, you can use an approach similar to weight decay.
- **Uncertainty Weighting:** This method involves weighting each task's loss by the model's uncertainty in that task, which is normally computed using the model output. It's actually a bit more complex and involves learning the weights as part of the model parameters.

**Backpropagation:**

When you have a single combined loss, you perform backpropagation on this loss. This updates all the shared parameters in your network.

**Separate Optimizers:**

Using separate optimizers for different layers or tasks is less common in multi-task learning, primarily because it complicates the training process. However, it might be beneficial in cases where tasks are very different and might require different learning rates or optimization strategies. In such cases, you would handle the losses separately and use different optimizers for different parts of the network.